# In ASP.net Core, How to post redirect user to another url with data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redirect

I want to redirect user to this address (POST and without Form):

```
example.com/save
```

data:

```
userId:  12
result: 95.7
```

Action:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Save()
{
   // here code
}
```

Comment: Hi @Gregg,Does your two actions in the same application?If so,you could try to use RedirectToAction.

Answer (score 0):

use HttpClient

```
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://example.com");
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("userId", "12"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("result", "95.7")
        });
        await client.PostAsync("Save", content);
    }
```

Comment: What should I return (Action)?

Comment: It depends on you,you could just return Ok().

Comment: @GreggMMichael please mark as an answer if you think so